# Chromium: Option to save passwords and change encryption greyed out

Tags: encryption, password, chromium

I am using Chromium build 353428 on PacROM 5.1. After signing in with my Google account,  I tried to set a separate sync passphrase (using instructions given [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?hl=en)). However, when I click on my account name second time (with caption "Please update your sign in details"), the next screen has entries for "Password" as well as "Encryption" greyed out. Curiously, in Settings → Save Passwords, the options to save passwords is active.

Do Chromium builds support saving passwords and encrypting them with separate passphrase? If yes, what might be causing the above mentioned behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A reboot might fix the issue (it did in my case). No idea what caused it though.